# Why does my mouse pointer in a browser disappear periodically?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, cursor

I experience the following type of problem: the mouse cursor, when in the browser window, starts blinking: several seconds it is visible, the next several seconds it isn't. It takes place in both browsers installed - IE and Chrome.

What could be the reason for that? How it could be fixed?

**Edited (added):**

After some research (installing additional browswers, closing opened pages one after another and then opening them one by one in a new browser) I found out that the reason for that was one page (one of the blogspot blogs). When this page was opened (in any browser) the effect of blinking appeared on every page in this browser.

Comment: though not a specific answer, some types of plugins and add-ons can hide the mouse cursor. Does this happen on all web pages, or just select pages. Provide more specific-use scenarios when it happens. What are you doing when it happens?

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, it seems you are right about effect of some plugins. Please, have a look at my edited question.

Comment: So the culprit is a web page, I wonder what it's trying to do with your cursor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not the web page that is trying to hide the pointer (does this happen on different pages?), then it could just be your mouse pointer options:

[image: mouse pointer options]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this option. It'll be helpful for me. +1 But, I'm afraid the problem in my case not in this checkbox (I've tried to uncheck it after you draw attention to it). I edited my question with some new info.

Answer (score 0):

i got this issue too. since i was stumbling on websites before i shut my computer off, the last page to come on on reboot was [this](http://www.lullatone.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/raindrop.swf) and whenever that page is loaded, my cursor goes bonkers on other tabs on my browser. so, if you've got lots of tabs open on your browser, check for which one of them has flash.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem on my Chrome browser (with a mouse pointer that's normal) by going to that link. In other tabs, the mouse cursor started disappearing whenever I stopped moving my mouse. It only appears when I'm moving it. To solve the problem, I closed the tab of that link. As soon as I closed that *Raindrop Melody Maker*, the problem stopped. (**PS:** You can stop *Shockwave Flash* plugin in *Chrome Task Manager* to solve this problem, especially if closing pages with Flash doesn't help.)

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix is to go to the Chrome settings and disable the Hardware Acceleration option. If this is already disabled, enable it or toggle it to resolve the issue. Don't forget to upgrade to the latest version of Chrome browser, irrespective of the platform that you are using.

Source, my post: [fix mouse disappearance issues in Chrome](http://www.faceofit.com/resolve-fix-mouse-disappearance-issues-chrome-windows-10/)